# Is there a way via Powershell to add a web service reference to a Visual Studio project?

Tags: web-services, visual-studio, powershell, asmx

Pretty simple question... I couldn't find anything online.  Is there a way via Powershell to add a web service reference (`.asmx`) to a Visual Studio project?

Comment: Do you mean "add a web reference to a visual studio project"?

Answer (score 1):

A Visual Studio project file is simple XML, so you can manually add it in Visual Studio, see what it looks like in the project file, and then look up how to change XML files using PowerShell.

For example:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjones/archive/2010/07/14/editing-xml-using-powershell.aspx

Comment: But, adding a service reference also adds entries to the web.config as well.  My guess is I would have to manually add those entries then?

Comment: Shockingly, web.config is an XML file as well. Whatever you learn about XML manipulation works for either file :-)

Comment: A little less flippant: if you're trying to do this to a running service (and if you are, WHY), you'll have to restart things for configuration changes to take effect.

Comment: The idea is to create a Powershell script that would simply add a web service reference (to an existing web service that our company uses) to an existing Visual Studio project, then once the script is created, I could then create a Nuget package that runs this script.  So essentially, creating a Nuget package that will install a web service reference to an existing Visual Studio project.

Comment: I did this, to the T, but when you add a web reference, VS adds "Service References" folder.  I can, too, add this folder, and the contents inside it, but inside Service References is my web service - and this does not have the normal "folder" icon next to it - it's its own icon.  However when I apply all of the changes like you recommend, the web service that's added to "Service References" adds it as a normal folder.

Comment: So obviously, adding it through VS does something different -- just compare the .vsproj files and see what you need to change.

Comment: Yeah, I did that... I created a vanilla project with a certain name, then created another vanilla project with the same name then added my web service reference.  I then used Beyond Compare to compare the two folders and I identified all differences it caught, including the .csproj changes.  I applied everything that Beyond Compare caught.  Not sure what adding a web service reference through VS does differently that doesn't cause at the very minimum a binary data change between the two projects... not sure where to go from here. :(

Comment: That's weird. I don't have Web development installed on my machine so I can't test this for you, sorry. If it's not in the vsproj and not in the .suo...